# mapr windows client not working

Tags: hadoop, mapr

I am trying to install mapr  windows client. I have followed all the steps outlined in the mapr windows client installation. I have copied the ssl_truststore file from our cluster into the C:\opt\mapr\conf folder and ran the configure.bat file. It ran without any errors and  I even verified the C:\opt\mapr\conf\mapr-clusters.conf with updated cluster name and CLDB nodes.

But however when i run the following command by changing to folder `c:\opt\mapr\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.0\bin`

`hadoop fs -ls /`

I get the following error

```
18/01/19 14:05:07 ERROR cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils: Exception during init
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.mapr.security.JNISecurity.SetClusterOption(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
at com.mapr.security.JNISecurity.SetClusterOption(Native Method)
at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.init(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:163)
at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.<init>(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:73)
at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.<clinit>(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:63)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.CoreDefaultProperties.<clinit>(CoreDefaultProperties.java:69)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2147)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProperties(Configuration.java:2362)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2579)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2531)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2444)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1156)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1128)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.setBoolean(Configuration.java:1464)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.processGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:321)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:487)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:340)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.mapr.security.JNISecurity.SetParsingDone()V
at com.mapr.security.JNISecurity.SetParsingDone(Native Method)
at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.init(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:231)
at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.<init>(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:73)
at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.<clinit>(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:63)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.CoreDefaultProperties.<clinit>(CoreDefaultProperties.java:69)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2147)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProperties(Configuration.java:2362)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2579)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2531)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2444)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1156)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1128)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.setBoolean(Configuration.java:1464)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.processGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:321)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:487)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:340)
```

We use java 8 and windows 7.

I am stuck with this issue for a while. I tried all the possible options but was not successful. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Guys any idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

These are steps :
1.      Install Mapr applications

2. Configure MapR client
      /opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -N poc2.cibdatahub.com -c -C (Ur cluster name)
3. Upload the missing jar from MapR cluster node to Edge node under:
       /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/yarn/
4. Create a local mapr account if you don't have one:

   ```
            Example: useradd mapr
            Passwd mapr
   ```
5. Set environment for user mapr

   ```
   su mapr
   vi ~/.bashrc
    #append line below
   export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0
   export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR
   export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
   export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
   #HIVE home directory configuration
   export HIVE_HOME=/opt/mapr/hive/hive-2.1
   export PATH="$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin"
   export HADOOP_USER_NAME="USERname"
   ```

   # load environment

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
6. Edit /opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/conf/spark-defaults.conf by adding

   ```
    spark.yarn.archive                 maprfs:///apps/spark/jars/spark-jars.zip
   ```
7. Verify the cluster setting

   /opt/mapr/conf/mapr-clusters.conf has option secure=false
8. Test

   ```
    hadoop fs -Dfs.mapr.trace -ls
   ```

Please try these options.